# Openlayers 3 get legend not working

Tags: openlayers, legend

So I am trying to display the appropriate legend for my first map. This is my javascript for my first_map.

```
function firstmap() {
    var first_map = new ol.Map({
        target:'FirstMap',
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                title: 'OSM',
                source: new ol.source.OSM()
            }),
            new ol.layer.Group({
                title: 'Overlays',
                layers:[new ol.layer.Tile({
                    title: '- NDVI',
                    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                        url: 'http://mygeonodeserver.org/geoserver/wms',
                        params: {layers: 'geonode:xyz',
                                      format: 'image/png'},
                        serverType: 'geoserver' }),
                    showLegend:true
                })]
            })
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
            projection: 'EPSG:900913',
            center:[3930427, 359171],
            zoom:6
            })
    });
    first_map.addControl(new ol3_legend({
    map: first_map,
    class: 'ol_legend' }));
}
```

The get legend java script i got online is this one below

```
<script type = 'text/javascript'>
function ol3_legend(e) {
    var options = e || {};
    var wmsVersion = options.wmsVersion || '1.1.1';
    var format = options.format || 'image/png';
    var legendP = document.createElement('p');
    legendP.innerHTML = 'Legend:';
    var legendDiv = document.createElement('div');
    legendDiv.className = options.class + ' ol-unselectable';
    legendDiv.appendChild(legendP);
    var layers = options.map.getLayers().getArray();
    for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
        if (layers[i].get('showLegend') === true) {
            try {
                var url = layers[i].getSource().getUrls()[0];
            } catch (err) {
                var url = layers[i].getSource().getUrl();
            }
            var legendImg = document.createElement('img');
            legendImg.src = url + '?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&sld_version=1.0.0&layer=' + layers[i].getSource().getParams().layers + '&format=' + format;
            legendDiv.appendChild(legendImg);
        }
    }
    ol.control.Control.call(this, {
        element: legendDiv
    });
}
ol.inherits(ol3_legend, ol.control.Control);

proj4.defs("EPSG:900913", "+proj=somerc +lat_0=47.14439372222222 +lon_0=19.04857177777778 +k_0=0.99993 +x_0=650000 +y_0=200000 +ellps=GRS67 +towgs84=52.17,-71.82,-14.9,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs");
</script>
```

The above script is not working because of my layers are grouped i.e new ol.layer Group

Comment: please see my updated post: http://webmappingtutorial.blogspot.hu/2014/12/controls-and-projections-in-openlayers.html

Comment: I saw your example Gabor it wont work with new ol layer Group({})

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I see your problem in full details. You have to modify your new code at two points.

- Check for the `showLegend` property.

Your first layer has an `OSM` source, which doesn't have a `getUrl` nor a `getUrls` function.

- Don't use the same index variable name in nested loops.

Let's say you don't get an error on the first layer. The second loop sets `i` to 0, the first loop comes again, and it looks for the first layer again. Infinite loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
    if (layers[i] instanceof ol.layer.Group) {
        var layersFromGroup = layers[i].getLayers().getArray();
        for (var j=0; j < layersFromGroup.length; j++){
            if (layersFromGroup[j].get('showLegend') === true) {
                try {
                    var url = layersFromGroup[j].getSource().getUrls()[0];
                } catch (err) {
                    var url = layersFromGroup[j].getSource().getUrl();
                }
                var legendImg = document.createElement('img');
                legendImg.src = url + '?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&sld_version=1.0.0&layer=' + layersFromGroup[j].getSource().getParams().layers + '&format=' + format;
                legendDiv.appendChild(legendImg);
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (layers[i].get('showLegend') === true) {
            try {
                var url = layers[i].getSource().getUrls()[0];
            } catch (err) {
                var url = layers[i].getSource().getUrl();
            }
            var legendImg = document.createElement('img');
            legendImg.src = url + '?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&sld_version=1.0.0&layer=' + layers[i].getSource().getParams().layers + '&format=' + format;
            legendDiv.appendChild(legendImg);
        }
    }
}
```

A more sophisticated, recursive method can be seen [here](http://webmappingtutorial.blogspot.hu/2014/12/controls-and-projections-in-openlayers.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to go through the list of layers of your layer group ([see api doc](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.layer.Group.html#getLayers))

```
var layers = options.map.getLayers().getArray();
for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
  if (layers[i] instanceof ol.layer.Group){
    var layersFromGroup = layers[i].getLayers().getArray();
    for (var i = 0; i < layersFromGroup.length; i++) {
       ... create the legend for each Layer
    }
  } else {
    ... create the legend for each Layer 
  }
```

With a bit of recursivity, it could be nicer.

Comment: thanks alot @oterrai so with your input i tweaked it on my end to make it recursive. The Final code is this

Answer (score 0):

by the help @oterrai i tweaked my code so that it can be recursive. 
a solution to those who are using ol3-layerswitcher

```
function ol3_legend(e) {
    var options = e || {};
    var wmsVersion = options.wmsVersion || '1.1.1';
    var format = options.format || 'image/png';
    var legendP = document.createElement('p');
    legendP.innerHTML = 'Legend:';
    var legendDiv = document.createElement('div');
    legendDiv.className = options.class + ' ol-unselectable';
    legendDiv.appendChild(legendP);
    var layers = options.map.getLayers().getArray();
    for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
        if (layers[i] instanceof ol.layer.Group){
            var layersFromGroup = layers[i].getLayers().getArray();
            for (var i=0; i < layersFromGroup.length; i++){
                try {
                    var url = layersFromGroup[i].getSource().getUrls()[0];
                } catch (err) {
                    var url = layersFromGroup[i].getSource().getUrl();
                }
                var legendImg = document.createElement('img');
                legendImg.src = url + '?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&sld_version=1.0.0&layer=' + layersFromGroup[i].getSource().getParams().layers + '&format=' + format;
                legendDiv.appendChild(legendImg);
            }
        }
    }
    ol.control.Control.call(this, {
        element: legendDiv
    });
}
```

Comment: i am getting this error when i use my customized code

TypeError: layersFromGroup[i].getSource(...).getUrl is not a function
 

var url = layersFromGroup[i].getSource().getUrl();

Comment: You double use the same index variable in two nested loops, change the second index var to some other name, like `for (var j=0; j < layersFromGroup.length; j++){`. This might not be the only problem, but you could try to change this and see if it works out.

Comment: @GaborFarkas: Hi, I am trying add legend to my map as well but I am getting the same error as paul: getUrls() not a function.